# WCF and Entity framework, hide a column/entity-property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

Is there anyway that I can hide the property of an entity from an entity-class/object?
In this case I dont want to expose a users Email adress.. but I still want to be able to POST a new User to the service..

**Edit**

Just to clarify what Im after..

I have a WCF Data Service thats "bound" to my Entity framework entities...
One of the entities is a "User-entity" which has a property called "Email"..
So what I would like to do is to be able to set which properties of the User-entity that I want to expose/show for the client that "consumes" the service.. I hope that makes it abit more clear :)

Comment: I think you're question is unclear.  You'd like your entity object to include all properties except the email address for a particular user but you would like to be able to post a new user along with a new email address?  Or will you add the address via other means?

Comment: Well.. I would like to hide the Email-property for all users.. But i still want to be able to set the Email-property if I would POST a new User into the database(by using a POST-request)

Comment: Try the IgnoreDataMemberAttribute on the property. WCF uses this when serializing data.

Comment: Oh, ok I will try that once Im back at work tomorrow :) Is it just to create a partial class of my entity-class and add that attribute above the property that I dont want to expose?

Answer (score 0):

Entities is a part of the DAL and can not be exposed by WCF Services. You need to create UserViewModel with properties that you want to show for the client.